# Using a custom target in nlog.config

Tags: nlog

I've been struggling with handling a custom target.

When I type in my config file, `type='MyTargetName'`, it doesn't recognize it, saying the xsd doesn't have a setting for it.

But, I've been reading and got the impression that xsd warnings don't effect the functionality.

Any tips on how you managed to get it working? Important to mention that my target works in run time, but not from the config file

Answer (score 1):

Adding below code to my nlog.config worked for me

```xml
<extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.MyTargetName"/>
</extensions>
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Register-your-custom-component